# Как изъять фрагмент кода методами php?

Tags: php

Есть код:

```
<select name="select"><option value="One option">One option</option><delimiter><option value="Me remember">Me remember</option><delimiter>
```

Фрагменты кода динамические.
Как из этого фрагмента HTML кода изъять содержимое value и добавить это в массив методами php?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1cd1e693af1afcaf8836b45c5ffdd34e2465fd83

Comment: Или парсер xml.

Comment: @u_mulder, но он будет работать медленнее чем регулярки :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '<select name="select"><option value="One option">One option</option>
<delimiter><option value="Me remember">Me remember</option><delimiter>';
preg_match_all('/value="(.*?)"/', $str, $output_array);
$ar_value = $output_array[1];
```

[Тест](https://ideone.com/Q2qVet)